# Call function for every row of a table without cross apply

Tags: t-sql

I have this tsql function which inserts into a table variable:

```
create function fnListInfo(@id int) returns @res table(
 [itemId] INT,
 [name] NVARCHAR(255),
 [type] NVARCHAR(20),
 [unit] INT,
 [order] INT
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @res

SELECT category.stockcat_id, category.stockcat_name, category.type, NULL /*unit*/, category.order
FROM tblStock stock
JOIN dbo.Map category on stock.id = category.itemId
WHERE stock.id = @id

insert into @res
    SELECT t.*
    FROM @res r
    CROSS APPLY dbo.anotherFunction(r.itemId) AS t
    WHERE r.type = 'parent'

RETURN
END
GO
```

In the end of fnListInfo, I want to add some more rows to the res table. If the row in @res is of type 'parent', I want to call another function (let's call it anotherFunction) which has the same return type as this one, and its input parameter is int (itemId from fnListInfo), and then I want to add the result from anotherFunction to @res in fnListInfo.

So basically I want to call anotherFunction for every row in @res which is of type 'parent' and append the result to the already existing @res.

I tried doing this:

```
insert into @res
        SELECT t.*
        FROM @res r
        CROSS APPLY dbo.anotherFunction(r.itemId) AS t
        WHERE r.type = 'parent'
```

and it works. The problem is that it's inefficient. Is there a better way?

I don't like using cursors.

Comment: Share function body and prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data

Comment: Do you really insert into `@res` within a function? Without knowledge about row counts, structure and possible indexes it is impossible to give advise... In your text you suddenly call it `#res`? If both a the same in structure a `UNION SELECT` might help. If your function is not "ad-hoc" (or "inline" or "single-statement") performance will be bad with many rows...

Comment: @lad2025 I added some code. It's actually a pretty simple function.

Comment: @Shnugo The #res was a typo. res is correct. I added some code, pls see.

Comment: What does the anotherFinction do ?  perhaps there is a better way to rewrite the entire select. Also, what is the explain plan ? If you use a temp table, then maybe indexing it will solve the performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your function to [`inline table valued function`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214762%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnListInfo(@id int) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
   SELECT t.*
   FROM (
        SELECT category.stockcat_id AS ItemId, category.stockcat_name AS name,
               category.type AS [type], NULL AS [unit] , category.[order] AS [order]
        FROM tblStock stock
        JOIN dbo.Map category 
          ON stock.id = category.itemId
        WHERE stock.id = @id) AS r
   CROSS APPLY dbo.anotherFunction(r.itemId) AS t
   WHERE r.type = 'parent'
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT category.stockcat_id AS ItemId, category.stockcat_name AS name,
          category.type AS [type], NULL AS [unit] , category.[order] AS [order]
   FROM tblStock stock
   JOIN dbo.Map category 
     ON stock.id = category.itemId
   WHERE stock.id = @id
);
```

You should change `dbo.anotherFunction` to inline table valued function too if possible.

I suggest also reading about **[`Inline vs Multistatement Table Function`](http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2012/02/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/)**

Comment: @petko_stankoski Updated

Comment: You might think about `CROSS APPLY`. Shouldn't it be `OUTER`?

Comment: @lad2025 Tnx for the solution. But how is that different from my code? Both use cross apply and I want to avouid that.

Comment: @petko_stankoski, I could not think of any reason why one should avoid `CROSS APPLY`... If this performs well or not is depending on the things you call inside...

Comment: @petko_stankoski [comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions](http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2012/02/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/)

Comment: @petko_stankoski Did you even try it?

Comment: @lad2025 I am trying it now. Your function returns SELECT t.*, that means it returns just the results from the anotherFunction. I dont get the results from r.

Comment: @petko_stankoski Added